# Zero matrix with non-zeros above diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on a square matrix consisting of zero entries, except the entries right above its diagonal are 1's. For example, matrix of 3 by 3 has 2 entries of 1's slanted parallel to its diagonal:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 &0\\
0 &0 &1\\
0 &0 &0\\
\end{bmatrix},$$
ect. And here are my two questions:
(1) Is there any name for that type of matrix? Any online reference to it?
(2) I am trying to prove, using only elementary means, that if $X_{k \times k}$ is such matrix, then its $k$ power equals to zero, while its $k-1$ power does not. Any link, hints, guidance or help will be very much appreciated.

Thank you for your time and effort.

---

**PS:** Getting good hints from Dirk below, I think it's should be called Shift Matrix, see the link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_matrix). The link even says that

> Clearly all shift matrices are nilpotent; an n by n shift matrix S becomes the null matrix when raised to the power of its dimension n...

Is there any proof relating to its being nilpotent, using elementary means? Thanks again to Dirk.

Comment: One helpful word is "nilpotent".

Comment: I think 2) would fail on a zero matrix with only 1 in top right corner

Comment: For $\lambda = 0$, this is in [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).

Comment: One interesting fact about the given matrix, call it $A$: for any $t\in\mathbb R$ we have

$$e^{tA} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & t & \frac12 t^2\\ 0 & 1 & t\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: Thanks to all. Getting hint from @Drk about Nilpotent, do you think it is what is called Shift Matrix? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_matrix

Comment: Work out all the powers in the $4 \times 4$ case. That might give you a hint about how to write a proof: where do the nonzero entries go when you compute the next power? You should be able to explain that in elementary terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly a matrix that represents a "shift" operation on a vector that represents a list, in the sense that it moves each entry "up" one step (and puts a $0$ in the last entry).

So a good inductive proof would work with "After $k\le n$ iterations, $A^k v$ has zero as its last $k$ entries, no matter what the vector $v$."